# "migrate:status" freezes on "Try to validate bootstrap phase 0"

Tags: drush, 9, migrations

Drupal community!

I am working on migrating from D7 to D9. Both are located on separate servers. I configured D7 database as db to migrate in my D9 settings.php, like this:

```php
$databases['migrate']['default'] = [
  'database' => 'dbname',
  'username' => 'username',
  'password' => 'password',
  'prefix' => '',
  'host' => 'd7_ip_host',
  'port' => '3306',
  'namespace' => 'Drupal\\Core\\Database\\Driver\\mysql',
  'driver' => 'mysql',
];
```

And when I try `drush migrate:status` or `drush migrate:upgrade`, Drush hangs on "Try to validate bootstrap phase 0."

The output of *Box Requirements Checker* is the following.

```
> Using PHP 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.11
> PHP is using the following php.ini file:
  /etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini

> Checking Box requirements:
  ✔ The package "composer/xdebug-handler" requires the version "^5.3.2 || ^7.0
|| ^8.0" or greater.
  ✔ The package "laravel-zero/phar-updater" requires the version "^7.3|^8.0" or
greater.
  ✔ The package "psr/log" requires the version ">=5.3.0" or greater.
  ✔ The package "webmozart/assert" requires the version "^7.2 || ^8.0" or
greater.
  ✔ The package "webmozart/path-util" requires the version ">=5.3.3" or greater.
  ✔ The package "webflo/drupal-finder" requires the extension "json".
  ✔ The package "webmozart/assert" requires the extension "ctype".

 [OK] Your system is ready to run the application.

 [preflight] Config paths: /home/mediaport.ua/www/vendor/drush/drush/drush.yml
 [preflight] Alias paths: /home/mediaport.ua/www/drush/sites,/home/mediaport.ua/         drush/sites
 [preflight] Commandfile search paths: /home/mediaport.ua/www/vendor/drush/drush         /src
 [debug] Bootstrap further to find migrate:status [0.06 sec, 9.44 MB]
 [debug] Trying to bootstrap as far as we can [0.07 sec, 9.44 MB]
 [info] Drush bootstrap phase: bootstrapDrupalRoot() [0.07 sec, 9.45 MB]
 [info] Change working directory to /home/mediaport.ua/www [0.07 sec, 9.44 MB]
 [info] Initialized Drupal 9.4.8 root directory at /home/mediaport.ua/www [0.07          sec, 9.45 MB]
 [info] Drush bootstrap phase: bootstrapDrupalSite() [0.07 sec, 9.46 MB]
 [debug] Could not find a Drush config file at sites/default/drush.yml. [0.07 se         c, 9.62 MB]
 [info] Initialized Drupal site default at sites/default [0.07 sec, 9.62 MB]
 [info] Drush bootstrap phase: bootstrapDrupalConfiguration() [0.07 sec, 9.62 MB         ]
 [debug] Add service modifier [0.07 sec, 9.88 MB]
 [info] Drush bootstrap phase: bootstrapDrupalDatabase() [0.08 sec, 10.42 MB]
 [info] Successfully connected to the Drupal database. [0.08 sec, 10.42 MB]
 [info] Drush bootstrap phase: bootstrapDrupalFull() [0.08 sec, 10.42 MB]
 [debug] Start bootstrap of the Drupal Kernel. [0.08 sec, 10.42 MB]
 [debug] Finished bootstrap of the Drupal Kernel. [0.13 sec, 17.27 MB]
 [debug] Add a commandfile class: Drush\Drupal\Commands\config\ConfigCommands [0         .21 sec, 27.38 MB]
 [debug] Add a commandfile class: Drush\Drupal\Commands\config\ConfigExportComma         nds [0.22 sec, 27.42 MB]
 [debug] Add a commandfile class: Drush\Drupal\Commands\config\ConfigImportComma         nds [0.22 sec, 27.42 MB]
 [debug] Add a commandfile class: Drush\Drupal\Commands\core\BatchCommands [0.22          sec, 27.43 MB]
 [debug] Add a commandfile class: Drush\Drupal\Commands\core\CliCommands [0.22 s         ec, 27.43 MB]
 [debug] Add a commandfile class: Drush\Drupal\Commands\core\DrupalCommands [0.2         2 sec, 27.44 MB]
 [debug] Add a commandfile class: Drush\Drupal\Commands\core\DeployHookCommands          [0.22 sec, 27.45 MB]
 [debug] Add a commandfile class: Drush\Drupal\Commands\core\EntityCommands [0.2         2 sec, 27.47 MB]
 [debug] Add a commandfile class: Drush\Drupal\Commands\core\LinkHooks [0.22 sec         , 27.48 MB]
 [debug] Add a commandfile class: Drush\Drupal\Commands\core\ImageCommands [0.22          sec, 27.49 MB]
 [debug] Add a commandfile class: Drush\Drupal\Commands\core\JsonapiCommands [0.         22 sec, 27.5 MB]
 [debug] Add a commandfile class: Drush\Drupal\Commands\core\LanguageCommands [0         .22 sec, 27.51 MB]
 [debug] Add a commandfile class: Drush\Drupal\Commands\core\LocaleCommands [0.2         2 sec, 27.52 MB]
 [debug] Add a commandfile class: Drush\Drupal\Commands\core\MessengerCommands [         0.22 sec, 27.54 MB]
 [debug] Add a commandfile class: Drush\Drupal\Commands\core\MigrateRunnerComman         ds [0.22 sec, 27.54 MB]
 [debug] Add a commandfile class: Drush\Drupal\Commands\core\QueueCommands [0.23          sec, 27.59 MB]
 [debug] Add a commandfile class: Drush\Drupal\Commands\core\RoleCommands [0.23          sec, 27.61 MB]
 [debug] Add a commandfile class: Drush\Drupal\Commands\core\StateCommands [0.23          sec, 27.63 MB]
 [debug] Add a commandfile class: Drush\Drupal\Commands\core\TwigCommands [0.23          sec, 27.64 MB]
 [debug] Add a commandfile class: Drush\Drupal\Commands\core\UserCommands [0.23          sec, 27.65 MB]
 [debug] Add a commandfile class: Drush\Drupal\Commands\core\ViewsCommands [0.23          sec, 27.71 MB]
 [debug] Add a commandfile class: Drush\Drupal\Commands\core\WatchdogCommands [0         .23 sec, 27.74 MB]
 [debug] Add a commandfile class: Drush\Drupal\Commands\field\FieldCreateCommand         s [0.23 sec, 27.78 MB]
 [debug] Add a commandfile class: Drush\Drupal\Commands\field\FieldInfoCommands          [0.23 sec, 27.79 MB]
 [debug] Add a commandfile class: Drush\Drupal\Commands\field\FieldDeleteCommand         s [0.23 sec, 27.79 MB]
 [debug] Add a commandfile class: Drush\Drupal\Commands\field\FieldBaseOverrideC         reateCommands [0.23 sec, 27.8 MB]
 [debug] Add a commandfile class: Drush\Drupal\Commands\field\FieldBaseInfoComma         nds [0.23 sec, 27.81 MB]
 [debug] Add a commandfile class: Drush\Drupal\Commands\pm\PmCommands [0.24 sec,          27.82 MB]
 [debug] Add a commandfile class: Drush\Drupal\Commands\pm\ThemeCommands [0.24 s         ec, 27.83 MB]
 [debug] Add a commandfile class: Drush\Drupal\Commands\sql\SanitizeCommands [0.         24 sec, 27.84 MB]
 [debug] Add a commandfile class: Drush\Drupal\Commands\sql\SanitizeCommentsComm         ands [0.24 sec, 27.84 MB]
 [debug] Add a commandfile class: Drush\Drupal\Commands\sql\SanitizeSessionsComm         ands [0.24 sec, 27.85 MB]
 [debug] Add a commandfile class: Drush\Drupal\Commands\sql\SanitizeUserFieldsCo         mmands [0.24 sec, 27.85 MB]
 [debug] Add a commandfile class: Drush\Drupal\Commands\sql\SanitizeUserTableCom         mands [0.24 sec, 27.86 MB]
 [debug] Add a commandfile class: Drupal\entity_reference_revisions\Commands\Ent         ityReferenceRevisionsCommands [0.24 sec, 27.86 MB]
 [debug] Add a commandfile class: Drupal\image_effects\Commands\ImageEffectsComm         ands [0.24 sec, 27.87 MB]
 [debug] Add a commandfile class: Drupal\migrate_upgrade\Commands\MigrateUpgrade         Commands [0.24 sec, 27.87 MB]
 [debug] Add a commandfile class: Drupal\token\Commands\TokenCommands [0.24 sec,          27.89 MB]
 [debug] Add a commandfile class: Drupal\views_bulk_operations\Commands\ViewsBul         kOperationsCommands [0.24 sec, 27.89 MB]
 [debug] Add a commandfile class: Drupal\webform\Commands\WebformCommands [0.24          sec, 27.9 MB]
 [debug] Add a commandfile class: Drupal\webform\Commands\WebformSanitizeSubmiss         ionsCommands [0.24 sec, 27.97 MB]
 [debug] Add a commandfile class: Drupal\pathauto\Commands\PathautoCommands [0.2         4 sec, 27.97 MB]
 [debug] Add a commandfile class: Drupal\xmlsitemap\Commands\XmlSitemapCommands          [0.24 sec, 27.99 MB]
 [debug] Done with bootstrap max in Application::bootstrapAndFind(): trying to f         ind migrate:status again. [0.25 sec, 28.02 MB]
 [info] Starting bootstrap to none [0.25 sec, 28.13 MB]
 [info] Drush bootstrap phase 0 [0.25 sec, 28.13 MB]
 [info] Try to validate bootstrap phase 0 [0.25 sec, 28.13 MB]
```

I do see that the connection with the remote database has been established, so I do not understand what is the problem.

> [image: screenshot]

Does somebody have any advice?

Regards

Comment: `migrate:status` queries information about all the migrations, how many rows total, how many processed, how many processed. This requires all the data from the source compared against all the data in the destination. If you have a lot of migrations, a lot of source data, a slow connection between systems, or any combination of these, `migrate:status` can freeze while doing all the comparisons (and emits nothing in the terminal while doing it). You can rule this out this by removing all but one small migration (one that only has a few rows) and try `migrate:status` again.